# Angular Material filtro de mat-table no funciona

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

tengo una tabla de angular material pero no me funciona el filtro

tengo mi informacion de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el filtro:

```
  <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-3">
              <div class="filter">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Filtro</mat-label>
                  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Buscador" #input>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

solo funciona si escribo el id pero los otros campos no, alguna idea?